# Using React hooks, how can I update an object that is being passed to a child via props?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks, parent-child

The parent component contains an array of objects.
It maps over the array and returns a child component for every object, populating it with the info of that object.
Inside each child component there is an input field that I'm hoping will allow the user to update the object, but I can't figure out how to go about doing that.
Between the hooks, props, and object immutability, I'm lost conceptually. 
Here's a simplified version of the parent component:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // makes an axios call and triggers setCategories() with the response
  }

  return(
    categories.map((element, index) => {
      return(
        <Child
          key = {index}
          id = {element.id}
          firstName = {element.firstName}
          lastName = {element.lastName}
          setCategories = {setCategories}
    })
  )
}
```

And here's a simplified version of the child component:

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return(
    <h1>{props.firstName}</h1>
    <input
      defaultValue = {props.lastName}
      onChange={()=>{
        // This is what I need help with.
        // I'm a new developer and I don't even know where to start.
        // I need this to update the object's lastName property in the parent's array.
      }}
  )
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre], but note that this isn't a tutorial service.

Comment: Forget hooks for this, do you know how to update an object in an array in an immutable way?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've just updated it. Hopefully that helps. I'm new to development and Stack Overflow, so I'm still getting used to how to ask good questions.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3001761; if you don't know where to start, a structured tutorial is likely a better choice than a SO question.

Comment: @azium Thanks for the reply. Should I ditch hooks and make it a class component? Kind of funny — I started this project as a way to familiarize myself with hooks. I suppose part of the learning process is learning when they are and are not useful. I do know how to update an object in an array in an immutable array.

Comment: @jonsharpe I've been looking for a tutorial on this specific question and haven't found one. I'll keep looking, but in the meantime, can you give me some guidance here? I appreciate your help.

Comment: no no, definitely use hooks. I just mean your problem doesn't relate to hooks. the issue is one of updating an array immutably. you would still have the same problem with a class, they're both unrelated to your actual problem

Comment: if you know how to update the array immutably, do that then pass that array to `setCategories` that's it

Comment: @azium Ohhh, got it. Okay, I'll try that. I've been informed that this kind of question is not what Stack Overflow is about, so I'll be deleting it. But this is actually quite helpful, so thank you!

Comment: Nah don't delete your question its fine. If you think you know how to update the array immutably post the code for that, then we can see where your'e going wrong. if you get an error, post that

Comment: Hey @azium the answer that was posted solved every problem I had. Just wanted to thank you for your patience and your help. I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe without knowing it, you have *lifted the state*: basically, instead of having the state in the `Child` component, you keep it in the `Parent`.
This is an used pattern, and there's nothing wrong: you just miss a handle function that allows the children to update the state of the `Parent`: in order to do that, you need to implement a `handleChange` on `Parent` component, and then pass it as props to every `Child`.

Take a look at this code example:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Making your AXIOS request.
    }, []);

    const handleChange = (index, property, value) => {
        const newCategories = [...categories];
        newCategories[index][property] = value;

        setCategories(newCategories);
    }

    return categories.map((c, i) => {
        return (
            <Child
                key={i}
                categoryIndex={i}
                firstName={c.firstName}
                lastName={c.lastName}
                handleChange={handleChange} />
        );
    });
}

const Child = (props) => {
    ...

    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        props.handleChange(props.categoryIndex, e.target.name, e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        ...
        <input name={'firstName'} value={props.firstName} onChange={onInputChange} />
        <input name={'lastName'} value={props.lastName} onChange={onInputChange} />
    );
}
```

Few things you may not know:

- By using the attribute `name` for the `input`, you can use just one handler function for all the `input` elements. Inside the function, in this case `onInputChange`, you can retrieve that information using `e.target.name`;
- Notice that I've added an empty array dependecies in your `useEffect`: without it, the `useEffect` would have run at EVERY render. I don't think that is what you would like to have.
  Instead, I guest you wanted to perform the request only when the component was mount, and that is achievable with n empty array dependecies;

Comment: You really took time out of your day to give me a simple, concise, and sufficient answer to my question. I can't tell you how much I appreciate you doing that. Thank you so much! Just added that to my code and it worked. And what's more: I understood why it worked. Thanks again!